# IrDa API for Windows 7 x64

Tags: c#, java, api, windows-7, infrared

Anyone knows a free API (preferencially in Java) for IrDa in to use in Windows 7 x64?

I need to send some data over an Actisys IR4000 but I don't have a clue.

Thnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does Java allow access to sockets types other that TCP/IP?  IrDA programming is via winsock, see my (big!) document http://www.alanjmcf.me.uk/comms/infrared/Microsoft%20Windows%20IrDA%20programming.html

Comment: that's big alright. For now I used IrCOMM2k to access IR like a comm port, but that only works for 32 bit. Next step it's to buy a x64 IrComm compatible IrDa (Actisys have one) or one with linux drivers (I guess that they have better API for that).

Comment: @alanjmcf - The link you have provided is blocked at my location.  Could you kindly email the content, perhaps as a pdf?  ryykblum@gmail.com